# Netbeans: Set up VM options for multiple dev environments?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, netbeans-7

Looking at LWJGL installation [here](http://lwjgl.org/installation.php).

I'm having to change the VM Options line (under Project Properties->Run) to run under Mac, even though I am continuing to develop in parallel on Windows.

That's really tedious, as I don't want to have to be changing the path each time I switch -- which will be all the time.

Any ideas on how I might get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two sets of configuration: In Project Properties > Run > New Configuration.

Create 2 configs (say "Win" and "Mac") with the respective VM Options.

You can then switch from one to the other with a right click on Project > Set Configuration > Win / Mac.